# Cant install Ops Agent on VM instances but Warning: apt-key is deprecated

Tags: ssh-agent

I have recently migrated my 3 websites from a standard server to the GCP -VM Instances (very happy with the performance improvement).

However, I cannot install an Ops Agent to view more stats on Observability. Could this be due to the SSL or something in this regard from the previous hosting company?

Please see below and advise on solution - much appreciated.

### W: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists/google-cloud-ops-agent-jammy-all/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
No changes made.
henracseo@henrac-litespeed-vm:~$ sudo apt-key list
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg

pub   rsa2048 2021-05-04 [SC]
35BA A0B3 3E9E B396 F59C  A838 C0BA 5CE6 DC63 15A3
uid           [ unknown] Artifact Registry Repository Signer artifact-registry-repository-signer@google.com

pub   rsa2048 2022-05-21 [SC]
A362 B822 F6DE DC65 2817  EA46 B53D C80D 13ED EF05
uid           [ unknown] Rapture Automatic Signing Key (cloud-rapture-signing-key-2022-03-07-08_01_01.pub)
sub   rsa2048 2022-05-21 [E]

### /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/lst_debian_repo.gpg

pub   dsa1024 2012-03-07 [SC]
4225 9994 257E 19EB 6A91  CA85 3F6F 6270 8308 4D0E
uid           [ unknown] LiteSpeed Tech Inc. (LiteSpeed GnuPG Key) info@litespeedtech.com
sub   elg2048 2012-03-07 [E]

### /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/lst_repo.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2016-10-27 [SC]
3E89 2522 DB44 E1B0 63D3  66C5 011A A62D EDA1 F085
uid           [ unknown] LiteSpeed Technologies Inc (LiteSpeed Technologies Inc GnuPG Key) info@litespeedtech.com
sub   rsa4096 2016-10-27 [E]

### /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb-keyring-2019.gpg

pub   rsa2048 2014-05-21 [SC]
13CF DE6D D9EE 9784 F41A  F0F6 70E4 618A 8167 EE24
uid           [ unknown] MariaDBManager

pub   rsa4096 2016-03-30 [SC]
177F 4010 FE56 CA33 3630  0305 F165 6F24 C74C D1D8
uid           [ unknown] MariaDB Signing Key signing-key@mariadb.org
sub   rsa4096 2016-03-30 [E]

pub   dsa1024 2010-02-02 [SC]
1993 69E5 404B D5FC 7D2F  E43B CBCB 082A 1BB9 43DB
uid           [ unknown] MariaDB Package Signing Key package-signing-key@mariadb.org
uid           [ unknown] Daniel Bartholomew (Monty Program signing key) dbart@askmonty.org
sub   elg4096 2010-02-02 [E]

pub   rsa2048 2014-12-18 [SC]
4C47 0FFF EFC4 D3DC 5977  8655 CE1A 3DD5 E3C9 4F49
uid           [ unknown] MariaDB Enterprise Signing Key signing-key@mariadb.com

pub   rsa4096 2017-10-16 [SC]
7B96 3F52 5AD3 AE62 5905  8D30 1356 59E9 28C1 2247
uid           [ unknown] MariaDB Maxscale maxscale@googlegroups.com
sub   rsa4096 2017-10-16 [E]

### /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) cdimage@ubuntu.com

### /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg

pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) ftpmaster@ubuntu.com

henracseo@henrac-litespeed-vm:~$